# Help Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-\log(x)^2}{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can I get some help integrating the following?

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-\log(x)^2}{2}}dx$

Apparently the answer I am supposed to get is $e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}$

I was told that I should use u-substitution and the Gaussian integral.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-u^2}{2}}du$

Where

$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-a(x+b)^{2}}\,dx={\sqrt {\frac {\pi }{a}}}.$

So $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-u^2}{2}}du = x^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=x^n$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you define $\log(x)$ for $x\leq 0$?

Comment: It is not specified in the question but the pdf is apparently based on the lognormal distribution.

Comment: This is $(\log(x))^2$ or $\log(x^2)$?

Comment: It is $(log(x))^2$

Comment: I guess lower limit of integration should be zero, instead of $-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

After you made the $u$-substitution $u=\ln(x)$, then $x=e^{u}$ so $x^{n}=e^{nu}.$ So the integral becomes:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{nu}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2}}du =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u^{2}-2nu)}du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}[(u-n)^{2}-n^{2}]}du$$

$$=\frac{e^{\frac{n^{2}}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u-n)^{2}}du=\frac{e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{2\pi}=e^{\frac{n^{2}}{2}}$$

since $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-n)^{2}}\,dx={\sqrt {\frac {\pi }{\frac{1}{2}}}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$ and by completing the square.

Comment: How do you determine $\log(x)$ for $x < 0$?

Comment: Thank you! I see exactly what I did wrong.

Comment: For the limits we choose $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\ln(x)=-\infty.$

Comment: And what is $\log{0}$?

Comment: $\log(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: Actually $\log{x} $ for $x \le 0$ is undefined. Otherwise it should be complex logarithm.

Comment: Does this mean that the above answer is not correct? Because as far as I can tell the Gaussian is defined on $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: The integrand function $x^ne^{-\frac{ln(x)^{2}}{2}}$ is not defined for $x<0$ (graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vpvlq1on4c), but it's tending to $0$ as $x\rightarrow\ 0^{+}$ (which is it's limit). So we consider the interval $[0,\infty)$ and using the substitution $u=\ln(x)$, we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\ln(x)=-\infty$. Thus the integration limits are correct.

Comment: Ah that makes sense